# Pie Chart with text outside pie

Tags: pstricks, charts

I'm able to draw pie chart using tex code mentioned below:

```
\documentclass[landscape,a3paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{pspicture}(-5,-4)(4,4)
\psset{unit=1.2}
\psChart[userColor={black!10,black!40},chartSep=10pt,chartNodeI=0.5,shadow,shadowsize=3pt]{10,90}{}{3}
\bfseries
\rput(psChartI1){Above 10 \%}
\rput(psChartI2){Below 90 \%}
\end{pspicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

I want to move text inside pie chart to outside (as highlighted in RED color) can you please suggest?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You must use the outer nodes (with letter `O`) for the positioning (see `texdoc pstricks-add`):

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-7,-4)(7,4)
\psset{unit=1.2}
\psChart[userColor={black!10,black!40},shadow,shadowsize=3pt, chartNodeO=1.15]{10,90}{}{3}
\bfseries
\ncline[arrows=<-, arrowscale=1.5, nodesepB=2pt]{psChartI1}{psChartO1}
\ncline[arrows=<-, arrowscale=1.5, nodesepB=2pt]{psChartI2}{psChartO2}
\rput[l](psChartO1){Above 10 \%}
\rput[r](psChartO2){Below 90 \%}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

That gives:

[image]

Comment: Thank You I'm able to get text outside, is there any way to draw arrow (from pie to outside text)?

Comment: Yes, see the edited answer, and `texdoc pstricks-add` ;)

Comment: :) Thank you ; it's working perfectly ; I'll surely read texdoc mentioned by you