# Pie Chart : Overlapping Text

Tags: xetex, pstricks, charts

I'm able to draw pie chart using tex code mentioned below:

```
\begin{center}
  \begin{pspicture}(-7,-4)(7,4)
    \psset{unit=1.2}
    \psChart[userColor={black!10,black!40,black!70},shadow,shadowsize=3pt, chartNodeO=1.15]{98,1,1}{}{3}
    \bfseries%
    \ncline[arrows=<-, arrowscale=1.5, nodesepB=2pt]{psChartI1}{psChartO1}
    \ncline[arrows=<-, arrowscale=1.5, nodesepB=2pt]{psChartI2}{psChartO2}
    \ncline[arrows=<-, arrowscale=1.5, nodesepB=2pt]{psChartI3}{psChartO3}
    \rput[c](psChartO1){98 \% scored more than you.}
    \rput[c](psChartO2){1 \% scored less than you.}
    \rput[c](psChartO3){1 \% scored equal to you.}
  \end{pspicture}
\end{center}
```

MWE  code is mentioned [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142379/pie-chart-with-text-outside-pie)

Issue is when two consecutive pie next to each other are very small (also sometimes text and arrow gets overlapped), text get's overlapped, sample image is mentioned below: 
[image]

Can you please suggest, how to correct this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One possibility is to use another reference point than `[c]` for `\rput`:

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt, pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-9,-4)(9,4)
  \psChart[userColor={black!10,black!40,black!70},shadow,shadowsize=3pt, chartNodeO=1.15]{98,1,1}{}{3}
  \bfseries%
  \ncline[arrows=<-, arrowscale=1.5, nodesepB=2pt]{psChartI1}{psChartO1}
  \ncline[arrows=<-, arrowscale=1.5, nodesepB=2pt]{psChartI2}{psChartO2}
  \ncline[arrows=<-, arrowscale=1.5, nodesepB=2pt]{psChartI3}{psChartO3}
  \rput[r](psChartO1){98 \% scored more than you.}
  \rput[lt](psChartO2){1 \% scored less than you.}
  \rput[lb](psChartO3){1 \% scored equal to you.}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to ensure text always outside the pie? For some of the scenerio, i'm getting text overlapped with the pie

Comment: In principle that could be done, but I don't think, that there exists a good automation to layout arbitrary labels taking into account their positions, alignment, length, overlap etc. You can make further manual adjustments of the node positions with e.g. `\rput([Xnodesep=0.1,offset=0.2]psChartO1)`.